# Apache camel REST DSL duplicating content-type

Tags: rest, apache-camel, dsl

Using the rest dsl of apache camel for some reason, I don't know how, the response of the requests is returning duplicate content-type.

[image]

Example of code

```
rest("/api").consumes("application/json").produces("application/json")
.get("/find").to("bean:beanProcessor?method=find");
```

But if i put this:

```
rest("/api").consumes("application/json").produces("application/json")
.get("/find")
    .route()
        .to("bean:beanProcessor?method=find")
        .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/json"))
    endRest();
```

The content-type response return only one "application/json".

Why this happens?

i - I'm using camel 2.15.5. 
ii - I try remove the consumes and produces, but the duplicate contunues.

Comment: What component are you using as rest, eg what did you configure in rest configuration?

Comment: I'm using "spark-rest"

Comment: thanks sounds like a bug with spark-rest, you are welcome to log a JIRA ticket at Apache Camel

Comment: Ok, thanks again @ClausIbsen

Comment: I logged a ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-9613